# Fastest way to set up IIS and PHP

Tags: php, windows, iis, installation

I tried to manually set up a PHP, IIS enviroment on windows 7, but it didn't work. I tried it hard, but never succeeded. 
What's the fastes and most sure way to set up php with IIS on windows?

Comment: Use the Web Platform Installer.

Comment: I tried first manually, the same way as what the first anwser suggests, but it didn't work, so I tried with the web platform installer. It installed, everything went fine, but when i tried to open a php file with a simple echo, it did nothing, I mean the website was: "<?php...

Comment: when I run php it opens up, but I my php files don't wokr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Web Platform Installer from MS:
http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/install.aspx?appid=PHP53

Or php.net has instructions for installing php under IIS:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

Comment: webplatform installer isnt better?

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to install php on Windows servers is by using [PHP Manager for IIS.](https://phpmanager.codeplex.com/)

This will do all the manual stuff like installing php runtime, configuring the fastcgi for iis , make sure everything runs fine is check phpinfo() ,also makes it easier to enable/disable php extensions.

But doing manually as linked by other answers will teach you all the things this tool does automated.so if something breaks,It will be easy for you to fix it.